# I need a web interface to run code on

Tags: open-source, web-apps, programming

I have a blade center where I would like to run code on it through a web interface. At the minimum, I should be able to write and execute code on the web interface. An example would be something akin to this:

https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler

I would be writing software for C++, R, and python. Separate packages for each is fine but it would be nice to find one universal one.

Here are my requirements for the software that I am looking to find

Min:

- Write and execute code (C++, R, Python)
- Separate packages for each
- Web interface (Go to IP address and run https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler)

Desired to Have

- Cluster computer support out of the box
- One universal package
- Can debug code in web interface

Preferably, this would be self hosting and free

Answer (score 1):

Try Rstudio Server. There is an [open-source edition](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download-server/) that you can set up on your own web server. There is a free [cloud offering](https://rstudio.cloud/plans/free) where you don't have to setup anything.

Answer (score 0):

You might check [AWS Cloud9](https://aws.amazon.com/de/cloud9/). Not self hosted but worth for a look.

Also interesting might be [Codetasty](https://codetasty.com).

Comment: Thanks but these cost money and are not self hosted, I am looking for self hosted options

Answer (score 0):

Try this --> **One Compiler** https://onecompiler.com/

I use it a lot to compile small amount of code.

Comment: Does this have a self hosting option?